# Unable to reproduce error in event viewer

Tags: asp.net, event-viewer

Recently i received below error in the production server's event viewer.
It appear every 5-10 mins and come from different user host address.
I tried to troubleshoot by clicking all the links in the default.aspx page but still unable to reproduce below error.

Anyone can give some suggestion how to solve below error?

```
Process information: 
Process ID: 18756 
Process name: w3wp.exe 
Account name: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM 

Exception information: 
Exception type: ArgumentException 
Exception message: Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.
at System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.ValidateEvent(String uniqueId, String argument)
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)



Request information: 
Request URL: http://domain.com/default.aspx 
Request path: /default.aspx 
User host address: 108.162.208.110 
User:  
Is authenticated: False 
Authentication Type:  
Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM 

Thread information: 
Thread ID: 8 
Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM 
Is impersonating: False 
Stack trace:    at System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.ValidateEvent(String uniqueId, String argument)
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is because you have EventValidation turned on, at page or website level. The error happens when you try to immitate an user's event (most propably using javasctipt). This gives asp.net an impression that the event was not actually triggere by the postback control.

Most probable place for this error to happen is when you are trying to create some controls dynamically (and the page is also using Update panel).

If you think you can not change the structure of the application then you may consider disabling Event validation on specific page (but before that identify the pages).

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. However, i tried run my application in local machine and it did not generate any error.

Comment: have you recently migrated from some old .net version?

Comment: no, the only migration i have done is server migration(db server)